# Indentation of code in Toad

Tags: oracle, toad, auto-indent

Is there any software or a shortcut key which I can use to auto-indent code in Toad for Oracle 11.6?

Comment: I assume you mean Toad, rather than 'tord' or 'tode'. [Does this help](http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC77029), or is specifically a shortcut key that you're looking for?

Comment: The shortcut for Format is CTRL+F. Formatting options can be configured in View-->Options. Select Formatting on the left side. If you just want to indent code by selecting a range then make your selection and press Tab. Tab increases the indent, Shift+Tab decreases it.

Comment: Correction, CTRL+Shift+F is the shortcut. At any rate, I see your post on ToadWorld. Our formatter developer will need to chime in. I don't see how to stack the columns when there is just one. If there are 2-N columns you can stack them, but the first column appears on the same line as the SELECT. There are numerous options though.

Comment: hi @user490358,
Thanks a lot for suggesting me to join in Toad. I am working with big codes, so I want to edit formatter once and use it for the entire code. But I am worried about not having idea about formatter. Please suggest some links so that I can find information about formatter.

Comment: You can search ToadWorld for "formatter" and you'll find many links. Be sure to set your filter after you get results to limit them to the Toad for Oracle or Toad for Oracle Beta forum. All of Dell's (formerly Quest) database tools have communities there. You might also have luck with a Google search for Toad Formatter. You'll find archived messages for the Toad groups when it was hosted by Yahoo Groups. I believe that Nabble.com has a lot of the archived messages or you can try Yahoo Groups directly. The old group may exist in a readonly state. Continued...

Comment: The formatter developer is in Europe and may not be at work at this time. He usually responds promptly when he's in the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right-click in the editor window and choose "formatting tools"/format.
How it does the formatting can be configured via View/Toad options/formatter.

[image]

Comment: Can I change the indentation according to me.... I mean to say SELECT empname will come in same line when i format but i want it to be in different lines.. Is it possible to custom the identation !!

Comment: Go into Toad's options and look at the Formatting page. There are many configurable settings in there. Play around with it until you find what you like. If you can't get it set to your liking then go to ToadWorld.com and sign up for an account. You can interact with the development team and formatting team directly there. It'll be your best place for help if you can't format it to your liking given the current option set.

Comment: Please see my amended answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is e.g. in SQL Developer. Shortcut for formatting code is CTRL + F7.

Answer (score 0):

CNTRL + SHIFT + I will do the work. this is in Toad

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure if it works in Toad for Oracle 11.6, but I used in other versions.

Method: Just select the lines of code you want to indent and press "TAB" Key on your keyboard, that will do the stuff.